# Can I make a web-crawler to get data from dynamic webpages by using powershell

Tags: powershell, web-crawler

I am doing a project of making a web-crawler,to get some information from a internal website. I found that the static pages could be catched by a few simple steps(setting cookies, and then use Cmdlet `Invoke-RestMethod`),but The data of dynamic pages are not be able to get this way. And also,I found The links on dynamic pages are not constantly, for example, it always constitutes of jsessionids or something,which always changing from time to time.

Can anyone please give me a hint to slove this problem? Can dynamic web pages be able to catched by crawler or not? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

maybe download strings, that should pull the HTML and you can pull your data from there even if its dynamic as its a snapshot in time.

or

```
  $site = "cnn.com"
  $sitedata = invoke-webrequest $site 
  $sitedata.rawcontent
```